# Перенос файлов из виртуальной машины kali linux на рабочий стол windows

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Пытаюсь настроить возможность переноса файлов из рабочего стола kali linux который находится в виртуальной машине на свой рабочий стол windows. Команда headers не исполнятеся. Подскажите пожалуйста что мне нужно сделать.

┌──(ali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ **sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)**

[sudo] password for ali:

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.18.0-kali5-amd64

E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-5.18.0-kali5-amd64'

Answer (score 0):

Нужно поставить гостевые дополнения virtualbox на linux (если вы используете его), далее создать общую папку в настройках виртуальной машины и перекинуть туда файлы